# Java - Run a method on Main thread, called from worker thread

Tags: java, multithreading

How can I call and run a method on the main thread, called from its worker thread?

Main Thread code, (Foo() function is accessible from Main Thread):

```
Thread newThread = new Thread(myThread, myThread.getThreadName());
newThread.start();
```

Worker Thread code (newThread):

```
@Override
public void run(){
// need to call from here Foo() function - it has to run on the main thread
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: Yes. I have a main thread that invokes a new thread (new.Thread.start()).

I need to execute a method (has to run on main thread), with arguments that are created on the worker thread - so I need to call the main thread from the worker thread

Comment: still not clear, can you add a  minimal code snippet?

Comment: this isn't enough, you have to show a full example, otherwise enjoy downvoting

Comment: Main thread -> creates a worker thread.
For example, only the main thread can call and run a "special method" -
and I need to call this method from the worker thread ->
So - how can I run this "special method" on the main thread, although it is called from the worker thread?

Comment: @Yoav take your time, edit your question (do not add comments), and include the **code** that you are running and what is the problem. The downvotes can be taken back, don't worry. Just improve your question, so that we can help

Comment: What is your main thread doing after it launches sub threads ? Does it wait or execute some other code ?

Comment: Actually there are two options - there is a flag "serialized". If its false it continues and executes the rest of the code. If it's true there is a "waitThreadsStopped()" method that is called (wait).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words "call a method in another thread" have no meaning in Java.

You need to understand that `Thread` and *thread* are two different things:  A thread is a path of execution through some code.  A `Thread` is a Java object that can be used to start a new thread and manage its life cycle.

A new thread begins when some other thread calls `t.start()` where `t` refers to a `Thread` object.  The thread begins executing the `t.run()` method, and it wanders into and out of function calls until it reaches the end of `t.run()`, at which point it dies.  Meanwhile, other threads are following their own paths through the code.

At the lowest level, the *only* way for one thread to interact with another is by updating the fields of shared objects and classes.

Thread A can *tell* thread B to execute some function or another by sending a message (i.e., by updating a field in some object), but thread A can never *make* thread B do something.  Thread B can only do what the code it is executing says to do.  If the code says, look at field `f`, and if its value greater than zero, then call function `foobar()`, then that is what thread B will do.  Or if the code tells it to pop a `Runnable` off of a queue and call the Runnable's `run()` method, then that is what the thread will do.

But no thread can change the *code* that some other thread is running once the thread starts running it.  It can only change fields that influence what the code will do next.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Can the main thread listen for events that are called from the worker thread? and if triggered execute some code?
Example: Main thread launches a worker thread, and after that enters a while(1) loop. Worker thread waits for some trigger - for example if the size of a folder is bigger then 1 MB, if so worker thread needs to notify main thread, and main thread will execute some code (although is in the while(1) loop)?

Comment: I like to define threads by what they wait for, and I like to see each thread waiting for just one kind of thing.  For example, a _worker thread_ sits in a loop waiting to `take()` a _task_ from a blocking queue.  When it gets one, it performs the task, and then goes back to waiting for the next.  A GUI _event thread_ waits for mouse or keyboard input, and then it locates an appropriate handler, calls the handler, and goes back to waiting.  It's up to you to decide what your main thread is going to wait for.  Messages from a BlockingQueue?  That works.